Как получить данные о созданом объекте используя google cloud firebase gen2 event onDocunentCreate, если получаю event: undefined
столкнулся с проблемой, не могу понять причину, по которым event:undefined и param: {}
При условии, что похожий функционал работает на ура
Вот код рабочего варианта:
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getAuth} = require("firebase-admin/auth");
const {
 onDocumentCreated,
 onDocumentDeleted,
 } = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {
 getFirestore,
 } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

const app = initializeApp();
const auth = getAuth(app);

exports.email = onDocumentCreated(
 "/RegistrationRequests/{requestId}",
 (event) => {
    console.log(event.data)
  
 },
);

Данный код выводит:
QueryDocumentSnapshot {
 _fieldsProto: { email: Value { stringValue: '123' } },
 ...

т.е. всё окей и классно, НО аналогичный ему кусок:
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {getAuth} = require("firebase-admin/auth");
const {
 onDocumentCreated,
 onDocumentDeleted,
 } = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
const {onCall} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const {
 getFirestore,
 } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

const app = initializeApp();
const auth = getAuth(app);

exports.sendRegistrationEmail = onDocumentCreated(
 "/Status/{requestId}",
 (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  
 },
);

В данном ивенте написал console.log(event) вместо console.log(event.data), иначе выводит просто undefined.
Данный код выводит полную ерунду:
{
 '0': 10,
 '1': 202,
 '2': 3,
 ...
 '459': 240,
 '460': 41,
 params: {},
 data: undefined
}

Сам ивент отрабатывает верно, т.е. при создании объекта в таблице, однако данные какие-то странные. В БД всего 2 таблицы и они не связаны между собой.
Подскажите в чём причина такого лога?
